# How to get full path (including mount directory) for file path?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm working on a plugin for Coda, and I'm running into a strange problem when trying to compare file paths to a sqlite row.

Basically, NSOpenPanel returns an NSURL which returns a path like this:

```
/Users/michael/Documents/xcode stuff/hM github/Plugin/filename
```

And Coda returns the current file path as this:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/michael/Documents/xcode stuff/hM github/Plugin/filename
```

I need to be able to retrieve a sqlite row tied to this file (which was initially created when the user selects a file through NSOpenPanel) given the path from Coda.

Is there a way to get a file's actual full path, including Volume information?
Alternatively, is there a better way to store a reference to a file that could be easily retrievable, regardless of the given path?

**update**

I've realized that Coda modifies saved files in such a way that you cannot rely on a file's inode number to remain consistent, so trojanfoe's answer will not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following:

```
miranda-6:~ jeremyp$ ls -l /Volumes
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   1 jeremyp  staff  8192 23 Oct 06:54 BOOTCAMP
drwxrwxr-x@ 20 jeremyp  staff   748 23 Oct 11:22 G-DRIVE
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root     admin     1 28 Oct 07:25 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxrwx   0 root     wheel     0  1 Nov 16:28 MobileBackups
miranda-6:~ jeremyp$
```

`/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is a symbolic link to `/`.

So what you should do (IMO), is iterate through the items in `/Volumes` until you find the one that is a symbolic link to `/`  Then whenever you get a file path from Coda that starts with `/Volumes/<the item linked to / >`, you strip that off before doing a search for it in your database.

You can use [NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW8) to find out if you have a symlink and [NSFileManager -destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW11) to find out where the symlink goes.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was looking at the problem backwards. The solution was actually pretty simple:

    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:somePath];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[url absoluteString]];
    NSString * newPath = [[url URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath] path];

Answer (score 1):

A better way to uniquely identify a file, regardless of how it's specified (absolute, relative, or including the mount) is to use the file's device and inode number which are unique across the system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static void get_file_details(const char *filename) {
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(filename, &statbuf) == 0) {
        printf("%s = %016llx%016llx\n", filename, (uint64_t)statbuf.st_dev, (uint64_t)statbuf.st_ino);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to stat '%s': %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        get_file_details(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o stattest stattest.c
$ ./stattest stat*
stattest = 00000000010000010000000001b1d48a
stattest.c = 00000000010000010000000001b1d43b
```

You'll need to decide how you *format* the device/inode combo, but the above format should work fine for most cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to pull the device and inode #'s through NSFileManager.

Comment: No! I've been thwarted by Coda. Apparently, however Coda decides to save files changes the inode number, rendering this method useless.

Comment: @mjvotaw Ah, that is a pain.  I guess you'll have to find some method of getting the absolute filename in a consistent manner (i.e. converting Coda's filename to a consistent format).